# Can I create an NLua.LuaFunction without the name of the Lua function?

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

I am trying to make a method that evaluates a string and returns a LuaFunction object for the function contained in it. These strings will be input by a user so I can't know the names of the functions beforehand. Example string:

```
function doSomething()
    print('x')
end
```

I want the LuaFunction to point to `doSomething`.

I was able to use a regex to capture the name of the function and then use NLua.Lua.GetFunction but that didn't work with functions in functions.

Right now my code uses KeraLua.Lua.LoadString and returns a LuaFunction for the chunk created by LoadString. This sort of works but it means the LuaFunction can't take args.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443998/get-list-of-functions-from-nlua) is similar to what I want, but I can't force the functions to be members of a table like it shows.

Comment: i do not believe you can get to an otherwise anonymous function, without accessing it through the table. can you accept `sometable.thefucntion` as an input? with the proper you can use that input to get to the function.

Comment: they aren't anon functions, I just don't know the name.

Comment: sorry may have misunderstood the question, are you trying to get the name of the function the user has just written, and the input is the whole function?

Comment: yeah ok well I mean I need to get the function without the name of the identifier

Comment: is the function definition format enforced? you could define it `doSomething = function()...` with or without a proceeding `local`, you can also define it in a table or even globally `_G['doSomething'] = function()...` are these in-scope for the solution?

Comment: if `doSomething` like I have in the question would be accessible `_G` then that would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219616/discussion-between-verygooddog-and-nifim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DoString` rather than `LoadString`. `LoadString` does not execute the code it just compiles it to be run later, so it does not define the function in state. the function must be defined for `GetFunction` or indexing to work.

If the input string is only a function define then you can do either of these:

```cs
Lua state = new Lua();
state.DoString((string)s); //define function in state by executing the input.

LuaFunction f1 = state.GetFunction("doSomething");
f1.Call("f1");

LuaFunction f2 = (LuaFunction)state["doSomething"];
f2.Call("f2");
```

Example user input:

```lua
function doSomething(s)
    print(s)
end
```

This solution does not cover local functions or functions which are stored in tables.

Comment: thanks, worked great. I used `NLua.Lua.GetObjectFromPath("_G").Keys` from before and after running the chunk and then did `Enumerable.Except()` to get the stuff that was added, and that means I don't have to know the name before hand! :)